# hermitian matrix-vector product does not give real result

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, products

*Background* : If $H$ is a **Hermitian** matrix, then for any complex vector $\psi$ it holds that $\psi^* \cdot H\cdot \psi$ gives a real number.

---

## The problem

I am creating a 16x16 Hermitian matrix in Mathematica (I am attaching code at the end of my question because it is quite large). Then, I construct some complex vectors and I compute the product stated above, e.i I do

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[wp[x0, y0]].H0.wp[x0, y0]]
```

Where `H0` is Hermitian matrix and `wp[x0,y0]` is a complex vector. My problem is that Mathematica cannot simplify the result to a real number, but complex exponentials are always present. Can somebody help me understand how I can use the simplification capabilities of Mathematica so that the code returns a real expression?

## The code

*Please note: I did not create a "minimal working example", because I don't care of simplifying an expression irrelevant to my problem and I can't be sure that whatever answer is given for a MWE would work for my case*.

I "declare" some variables as real:

```
Im[\[Alpha]] ^:= 0; Conjugate[\[Alpha]] ^:= \[Alpha]
Im[x0] ^:= 0; Conjugate[x0] ^:= x0
Im[y0] ^:= 0; Conjugate[y0] ^:= y0
Im[B] ^:= 0; Conjugate[B] ^:= B
Im[t] ^:= 0; Conjugate[t] ^:= t
Im[kx] ^:= 0; Conjugate[kx] ^:= kx
Im[ky] ^:= 0; Conjugate[ky] ^:= ky
a1 = \[Alpha]*Sqrt[3]*{1, 0};
a2 = \[Alpha] * Sqrt[3]*{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
\[Delta] = {0, \[Alpha]}
```

Then I create the Hermitian matrix $H$ (Tight-Binding Hamiltonian for any experts)

```
pos = Range[16];
pos[[9]] = {x0, y0};
pos[[2]] = pos[[9]] - a1;
pos[[6]] = pos[[9]] - a2;
pos[[16]] = pos[[9]] + a1;
pos[[12]] = pos[[9]] + a2;
pos[[4]] = pos[[9]] - a1 + a2;
pos[[14]] = pos[[9]] + a1 - a2;
pos[[7]] = pos[[9]] + 2 a2 - a1;
pos[[10]] = pos[[9]] - 2 a2 + a1 + \[Delta]
Do[
  pos[[i - 1]] = pos[[i]] + \[Delta],
  {i, {2, 6, 4, 9, 14, 16, 12}}];

hmatrix[n_, m_] := Which[
    n == m,
        0,
    Norm[pos[[n]] - pos[[m]]] === Abs[\[Alpha]],
        Block[
            {xn = pos[[n]][[1]], yn = pos[[n]][[2]],
                xm = pos[[m]][[1]], ym = pos[[m]][[2]]},
            -t*Exp[-I*B*((yn + ym)/2)*(xm - xn)]],
    True,
        0]

H = Table[hmatrix[i, j], {i, 16}, {j, 16}];
H0 = H /. B -> 0;
```

And indeed mathematica confirms that both `H`, `H0` are Hermitian, as `Transpose[Conjugate[H]] == H` returns `True`.

I now create the complex vectors $\psi$:

```
pw = Table[Exp[I (kx*pos[[i]][[1]] + ky *pos[[i]][[2]])], {i, 16}];
gaussian[a_, b_] :=  
  Table[Exp[-(pos[[i]][[1]] - a)^2 - (pos[[i]][[2]] - b)^2], {i, 16}];
wp[a_, b_] := (g = gaussian[a, b]; Table[g[[i]]*pw[[i]], {i, 16}]);
```

Now, I compute the expression of interest, namely $\psi^* \cdot H\cdot \psi$. As expected, the first complex vector `pw` gives a real result,

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[pw].H0.pw]
```

returns

$$
-2 t \left(12 \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\alpha  \text{ky}}{2}\right)+7 \cos (\alpha  \text{ky})\right)
$$

However, quite unexpectedly,

```
FullSimplify[Conjugate[wp[x0, y0]].H0.wp[x0, y0]]
```

does not return a real result, in the sense that Mathematica cannot simplify it:

$$
t \left(-e^{-\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(32 \alpha +i \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+2 i \text{ky}\right)}\right) \left(2 e^{6 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}}+2 e^{12 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}}+e^{15 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}}+2 e^{6 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(\sqrt{3} \text{kx}+4 \text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+i \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}+\frac{3 i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(2 \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+\text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(\sqrt{3} \text{kx}+4 \text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{12 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(2 \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+\text{ky}\right)}+e^{15 \alpha ^2+\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(2 \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+\text{ky}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(2 \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+\text{ky}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} i \alpha  \left(2 \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+3 \text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(24 \alpha +2 i \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+3 i \text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(24 \alpha +i \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+4 i \text{ky}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(30 \alpha +2 i \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+3 i \text{ky}\right)}+e^{\frac{1}{2} \alpha  \left(30 \alpha +i \sqrt{3} \text{kx}+4 i \text{ky}\right)}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+\frac{i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+2 e^{9 \alpha ^2+\frac{3 i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+2 e^{12 \alpha ^2+\frac{i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+e^{15 \alpha ^2+\frac{i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+e^{15 \alpha ^2+\frac{3 i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+e^{\frac{i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+e^{\frac{3 i \alpha  \text{ky}}{2}}+2 e^{\frac{3}{2} \alpha  (8 \alpha +i \text{ky})}\right)
$$

I have noticed this happening in many different cases. For some vectors the simplification works, for some others not. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel kind of dumb, but I found the answer to my own question in Mathematica's documentation. The function `ComplexExpand` is what I should be using.

Doing

```
Simplify[ComplexExpand[Conjugate[wp[x0, y0]].H0.wp[x0, y0]]]
```

instead of what I have in the original post, returns

$$
-2 e^{-16 \alpha ^2} t \left(2 \left(e^{9 \alpha ^2} \left(2 e^{3 \alpha ^2}+e^{6 \alpha ^2}+2\right)+1\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \alpha  \text{kx}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\alpha  \text{ky}}{2}\right)+e^{6 \alpha ^2} \left(2 e^{3 \alpha ^2}+2 e^{6 \alpha ^2}+e^{9 \alpha ^2}+2\right) \cos (\alpha  \text{ky})\right)
$$
which is real as expected!

Most importantly, this also correctly simplifies to real much more complex expressions than the ones mentioned here *and* it can get away with using `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify`!